# When to dispose of a HttpResponseMessage or a HttpContent

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm setting up an API to interact with a database and when the api receives a post to create an entry that is already present on it's respective table I want to return a code 209 Conflict with an explanatory message. So I tried this:

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostOrganizationAsync(Organization organization)
{
    using (var context = new ContextHandler())
    {
        bool added = await context.AddOrganizationAsync(organization);
        if (added)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            using (var httpContent = new StringContent("An organization with this Id already exists on the database"))
            {
                return new CustomHttpResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, httpContent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ContextHandler**

```
class ContextHandler : IDisposable
{
    static AuditLogsEntities LogDatabaseContext;

    public ContextHandler()
    {
        LogDatabaseContext = new AuditLogsEntities();
        LogDatabaseContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        LogDatabaseContext.Dispose();
    }

    public async Task<bool> AddOrganizationAsync(Organization organization)
    {
        var findOrg = await LogDatabaseContext.OrganizationSet.FindAsync(organization.Id);
        if (findOrg != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            LogDatabaseContext.OrganizationSet.Add(organization);
            await LogDatabaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomHttpResponse**

```
public class CustomHttpResponse : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode;
        public HttpContent Content;

        public CustomHttpResponse(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, HttpContent httpContent)
        {
            StatusCode = httpStatusCode;
            Content = httpContent;
        }

#pragma warning disable CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
#pragma warning restore CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
        {
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = null;
            using (httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(StatusCode))
            {
                httpResponse.Content = Content;
                return httpResponse;
            }         
        }
    }
```

Posting a new valid entry works fine, but trying to post an already existing one to test the 209 response results in an `ObjectDisposedException`, which I assume happens because of one of my `using` blocks, but the issue is I'm not sure which block it is and why it would result in an error.

EDIT: I somehow only now realized that according to the StackTrace, the exception is thrown when the `private HttpRequestMessage _request` property is being set inside `HttpResponseMessage`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use using blocks. Just store them in a private variable and dispose of them with the controller disposal. Also, you can use Task.FromResult for already completed tasks.

**Controller**

```
private StringContent _httpContent
private CustomHttpResponse _customHttpResponse

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostOrganizationAsync(Organization organization)
{
    using (var context = new ContextHandler())
    {
        bool added = await context.AddOrganizationAsync(organization);
        if (added)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            this._httpContent = new StringContent("An organization with this Id already exists on the database"))
            this._customHttpResponse = new CustomHttpResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, httpContent);
            return this._customHttpResponse;
        }
    }
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (this._httpContent != null)
        {
            this._httpContent.Dispose();
        }
        if (this._customHttpResponse != null)
        {
            this._customHttpResponse.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomHttpResponse**

```
public class CustomHttpResponse : IHttpActionResult
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode;
    public HttpContent Content;

    public CustomHttpResponse(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, HttpContent httpContent)
    {
        StatusCode = httpStatusCode;
        Content = httpContent;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(StatusCode);
        httpResponse.Content = Content;
        return Task.FromResult(httpResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, just to clarify it, does this means the controller implementation of asp.net creates an instance of the controller when it receives a request then disposes it after the controller sends the response?

Comment: @Lucas correct. The controller class has changed over time but all of them have some disposal mechanism. Core for example doesn't implement IDisposable but it has a resolver that can be used to register for disposal. Earlier versions just implemented IDisposable and dispose is called at the end of the pipeline.